# How can I make a multiple inheritance arrow relationship in Visio?

Tags: uml, microsoft-visio-2013

Is it possible to make the inheritance arrows just like in the Image bellow in Visio 2013 ?  I am trying but I just can't make it happen. I have multiple classes that inherit from one class and I want to do the connection just like in the image below. How can I make it as in the image below in Visio 2013 ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I stumbled on this and remembered your question. It might be what you're looking for.

Under 'View' from the ribbon select 'Snap & Glue' as shown below (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)

[image]

Under the Advanced Tab you can select 'Segment Midpoint' which seems to allow connections points on connection lines.

[image]

Not entirely sure if this is what you where trying trying to do, or if you had already ruled this option out, but here it is for your consideration.

Comment: I accept as a answer and +1. This option should be actually selected in Visio 2013 by default. It is really important for making good looking but also understandable UML diagrams. Also it is very well hidden. I wonder what the other options do.

Comment: I am ticking them as we speak ;) glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

There seems no way to do this automatically in Visio 2013 or select a shape/stencil but you have to be a little creative and do it yourself. First you have to connect the Classes with a simple association and then select a Inheritance relation/Arrow and glue it with the association lines you made. One example is in the image below. But Visio should be able to do this automatically or offer such connection.

[image: Visio Inheritance Relationship with more than one Arrow shape]